# WebJob calling WebAPI in Azure ASE can't resolve WebAPI name

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, ase

I have a WebJob and a WebAPI deployed to 2 separate App Services in a single Azure ASE (internal). I would like to call the WebAPI from the WebJob, but the WebJob fails to resolve the endpoint of the WebAPI.

Using the Kudo console from the WebJob confirms that Azure DNS is being used, and the service cannot resolve the internal name.

How can I get the name resolution working in this scenario?

[image]

Comment: According to the error message, your webapi URL is wrong.

Comment: If you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding a Private DNS Zone in for 2 names - the service name and the .scm service name. Then linked to the VNET that the ASE was in. Restarted the App Service.